# Deploying multiple apps on a single server with Phusion Passenger

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, meteor

I am currently running a simple Meteor.js application on a server using Phusion Passenger + Nginx.

What I would like to do is to configure it so that I have one main app on `www.example.com` and additional apps on `www.example.com/app1`, `www.example.com/app2` and so on. How can I achieve this configuration using the above-mentioned tools? I know how to do this using only nginx, but it seems like additional configuration for Passenger is required.

My current nginx configuration is as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
  root /var/www/app1/bundle/public;

  passenger_friendly_error_pages on;

  # Turn on Passenger
  passenger_enabled on;
  # Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app
  passenger_app_type node;
  passenger_startup_file main.js;

  # Tell your app where MongoDB is
  passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/app1;
  # Tell your app what its root URL is
  passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://www.example.com/app1;
}
```

This serves the application on `www.example.com/`, but I would like to move it to `www.example.com/app1/`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do the same thing. It works but [I still do have a small problem with my assets](https://serverfault.com/questions/743737/nginxpassenger-serving-assets-on-sub-uri) (I use rails)

In your **server** block you want to add a **location** block.

Here is how I do it:

```
location ~ ^/app1(/.*|$) {
    root /srv/www/app1/current/public;

    passenger_base_uri /app1;
    passenger_app_root /srv/www/app1/current;
    passenger_document_root /srv/www/app1/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

And now example.com/app1 serves your app.

Add as many location **block** as you want on the same pattern for more apps.

Comment: Root should be  '/srv/www'. Web server appends app1. Regex in app1 is disgarded here.  On difference between `alias` and `root`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10631933/1086346